# Is this Markov Chain calculation correct?

Tags: probability, markov-process

> $S=\{1,2\}$
>   $\alpha = (1/2, 1/2)$
>   $P= \begin{bmatrix}
> 1/2&1/2\\
> 0&1\end{bmatrix} $
>
> Find
>
> - $P(X_1=1 | X_0=1)$

**Given solution:**

$P(X_1=1 | X_0=1) = \frac{P(X_1=1 , X_0=1)}{P(X_0=1)} = \frac{P(X_1=1)  \cdot  P( X_0=1)}{P(X_0=1)} = 0.5 * 0.5 / 0.5 = 0.5$

---

To me, this is incorrect.

Because, $P(X_1=1) = 0.25$ ....  as $\alpha \cdot P = (0.25, 0.75)$

$P(X_0=1) = 0.5$ is correct as the 1st element of $\alpha = (1/2, 1/2)$  is $0.5$.

So, the answer should be $0.25$.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t quite agree with the provided solution but the question can directly be answered using your probability matrix, since $P_{ij}=P(X_{k+1}=i\vert X_k=j)$ for any non-negative $k$.